# A question about the February 26,2006 Richard Stanley Introduction to Hyperplane Arrangements

Tags: polynomials, power-series

My question is about this pair of sentences near the top of Richard Stanley's [Introduction to Hyperplane Arrangements.](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ecis6100/sp06stanley.pdf)

"We also write $[t^{k}]χ(t)$ for the coefficient of $t^{k}$ in the polynomial or power series $χ(t)$.
For instance, $[t^{2}](1 + t)^{4} = 6$."

I don't know why they are obtaining polynomials as terms of the power series and I don't know why χ(t) is a coefficient of the polynomial or power series that is χ(t).

Comment: You don't know what type of polynomial $(1+t)^4$ is?

Comment: Just how can you write χ(t) for a coefficient of the polynomial that is χ(t)?

Comment: You don't write $\chi(t)$ for the coefficient, we write $[t^k]\chi(t).$ The $[t^k]$ indicates which coefficient we are seeking.

Comment: Note, this is purely notation, not. statement of fact. It just means $[x^n]f(x)$ is the coefficient of $x^n$ in the Taylor series for $f.$ So you'll see: $[z^3]\log(1+z)=\frac13,$ or $[w^n]\frac{1}{(1-w)^2}=n+1.$ Sometimes you'll even see slight variants: $[x^n/n!]e^x=1$ or Taylor series around another point $[(x-2)^3]f(x)$ or functions of multiple variables: $[x^n] f(x,y)=g(y).$

Comment: i thought that it was a term in the polynomial by mistake. it's fine now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably overthinking this. We have $(1+t)^4 = 1 + 4t + 6t^2 + 4t^3 + t^4$, and the coefficient of $t^2$ is 6.  So $[t^2](1+t)^4 = 6$.

Comment: I didn't get it because it looks like a polynomial that's equal to 6... when i tried and figure out what that would be for i decided to post here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are confused because Stanley just previously defines $[n]=\{1,2,\dots,n\},$ and this statement about $[t^k]\chi(t)$ is broken out of the list of notations, so it looks like an application of the prior notation.

Stanley here is defining another notation, separate from the previous $[n].$ This notation also uses square brackets, so it might be confusing to see the two defined right next to each other.

From a analytic point of view, we might write:

$$[t^n]f(t)=\frac1{n!}f^{(n)}(0),$$ where $f^{(n)}$ is the $n$th derivative of $f.$

Now, technically, this only applies to analytic functions - functions $f$ whose Taylor series converges to $f$ in some open region around $0.$ But mathematicians also deal with abstract power series, where we don't care about convergence for particular values $x.$

For example, $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^nx^n$$ is a power series that does not converge for any non-zero real $x,$ but it is still an abstract power series, and we still say $[x^k]f(x)=k^k.$

This is most useful if you can write your polynomial or power series in a closed form. For example:

$$[x^k]\frac1{(1-x)^{n+1}}=\binom{n+k}{n}$$

or $$[y^k]e^{ay}=\frac{a^k}{k!}$$